# Terraform simple script says "Error: Error launching source instance: VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Getting started on Terraform. I am trying to provision an EC2 instance using the following .tf file. I have a default VPC already in my account  in the AZ I am trying to provision the EC2 instance.

```
# Terraform Settings Block
 terraform {
      required_providers {
         aws = {
             source  = "hashicorp/aws"
             #version = "~> 3.21" # Optional but recommended in production
        }
     }
 }

  # Provider Block
  provider "aws" {
        profile = "default"
        region  = "us-east-1"
  }

  # Resource Block
  resource "aws_instance" "ec2demo" {
           ami           = "ami-c998b6b2" 
           instance_type = "t2.micro"
  }
```

I do the following Terraform commands.

1. terraform init
2. terraform plan
3. terraform apply

aws_instance.ec2demo: Creating...

Error: Error launching source instance: VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user. GroupName is only supported for EC2-Classic and default VPC.
status code: 400, request id: 04274b8c-9fc2-47c0-8d51-5b627e6cf7cc

on ec2-instance.tf line 18, in resource "aws_instance" "ec2demo":
18: resource "aws_instance" "ec2demo" {

Answer (score 25):

As the error suggests, it doesn't find the default VPC in the us-east-1 region.
You can provide the `subnet_id` within your VPC to create your instance as below.

```
 resource "aws_instance" "ec2demo" {
           ami           = "ami-c998b6b2" 
           instance_type = "t2.micro"
           subnet_id = "subnet-0b1250d733767bafe"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now if there is any default VPC available in the AWS account then using terraform resource `aws_instance` instance can be created without any network spec input.

**Official AWS-terraform example:**
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#basic-example-using-ami-lookup

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id ## Or use static AMI ID for testing.
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
}
```

The error message: `Error: Error launching source instance: VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user.` states that the EC2 instance did not find any networking configuration in your terraform code where it needs to create the instance.

This is probably because of the missing default VPC in your AWS account and it seems that you are not passing any network config input to terraform resource.

Basically, you have two ways to fix this

- Create a default VPC and then use the same code.

  - **Document:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc
- Another and better way would be to inject the network config to `aws_instance` resource.  I have used the example from the [official aws_instance resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#network-and-credit-specification-example). Feel free to update any attributes accordingly.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "172.16.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "tf-example"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "172.16.10.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"

  tags = {
    Name = "tf-example"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "foo" {
  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.my_subnet.id
  private_ips = ["172.16.10.100"]

  tags = {
    Name = "primary_network_interface"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  ami           = "ami-005e54dee72cc1d00" # us-west-2
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.foo.id
    device_index         = 0
  }

  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }
}
```

Another way of passing network config to ec2 instance is to use [subnet_id](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#subnet_id) in `aws_instance` resource as suggested by others.

Answer (score 1):

Are there probabilities that you deleted the default vpc, if u did u can recreate going to the VPC Section  -> My Vpcs -> At the right corner you will see a dropdown called actions click and select create a default vpc

Answer (score 1):

I'm only create a Default VPC in AWS

1. **AWS VPC**
2. **actions**
3. **create default VPC**

it's done, **you try again now**

1. **terraform plan**
2. **terraform apply**

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33454638)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `main.tf` file and add:

```
subnet_id = "subnet-***********"
```

You can obtain it from VPC dashboard>subnets

Comment: The most top answer already shows to use "subnet_id".

Answer (score 0):

As the AWS announcement last year `On August 15, 2022 we expect all migrations to be complete, with no remaining EC2-Classic resources present in any AWS account.` From now on you will need to specify while you are creating any new resources the `subnet_id` and declare it inside your while creating.
Example :

```
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
  ami                    = "ami-xxxxx"
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-xxxxxxx"]
  subnet_id              = "subnet-xxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

First I search VPC service on the top bar and then in the left menu select the subnet's i have a few subnet's then i get the subnet id an paste in the field, and finally run a terraform apply and it works.

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_iac_instance" {
    ami= "ami-0e731c8a588258d0d"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    subnet_id = "subnet-***************"
    tags = {
        "Name" = "My IaC Instance"
        "Origin" = "Terraform"
    }
}
```